# SQL JOIN: How to echo values of a column of table A with same name as a column of table B?

Tags: mysql, join, echo

I have two MySQL tables with the name **accounts**

```
id username role
1  pete101  2
2  JohnnyA  1
3  Anno65   1
4  tom      1
5  koala3   2
```

and with the name **events**

```
id date     accountID
1  02-04-20 3
2  10-04-20 5
3  07-04-20 4
4  10-04-20 2
5  10-04-20 1
```

Now I want to show in a HTML table all events with the date '10-04-20' from the accounts with role '2'. 
I use this query for it: `"SELECT * FROM events JOIN accounts ON events.accountID = accounts.id WHERE events.date = '10-04-20' AND accounts.role = '2'"`

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){   
    echo "<tr><td>" . $row['id'] . "</td><td>" . $row['date'] . "</td><td>" . $row['username'] . "</td><td>" . $row['accountID'] . "</td><br>"; 
}
```

The result of this query (and PHP) is the next:

```
id  date     username accountID
5  10-04-20  koala3   5
1  10-04-20  pete101  1
```

It shows twice the id of the **accounts** table but I want the next echo:

```
id  date     username accountID
2  10-04-20  koala3   5
5  10-04-20  pete101  1
```

So the first column is the id of the **events** table and the last column (accountID) the id of the **accounts** table

What do I have to do to fix this?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: instead of row['id']... try row[0], row[1]...

Comment: Thanks, $row[0] did the trick. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it helped in comment, might aswell make it an answer. Changing it from `$row['colname'];` to its actual position in `$row`

Change original Query:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){   
    echo "<tr><td>" . $row['id'] . "</td><td>" . $row['date'] . "</td><td>" . $row['username'] . "</td><td>" . $row['accountID'] . "</td><br>"; 
}
```

To this:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){   
    echo "<tr><td>" . $row[0] . "</td><td>" . $row[1] . "</td><td>" . $row[2] . "</td><td>" . $row[3] . "</td><br>"; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

> ```
> CREATE TABLE accounts
>     (`id` int, `username` varchar(7), `role` int)
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO accounts
>     (`id`, `username`, `role`)
> VALUES
>     (1, 'pete101', 2),
>     (2, 'JohnnyA', 1),
>     (3, 'Anno65', 1),
>     (4, 'tom', 1),
>     (5, 'koala3', 2)
> ;
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE events
>     (`id` int,  `date` date, `accountID` varchar(10))
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO events
>     (`id`, `date`, `accountID`)
> VALUES
>     (1, '02-04-20', 3),
>     (2, '10-04-20', 5),
>     (3, '07-04-20', 4),
>     (4, '10-04-20', 2),
>     (5, '10-04-20', 1)
> ;
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
> e.id,a.username,e.`date`, e.accountID
> FROM events e JOIN accounts a ON e.accountID = a.id 
>  WHERE e.date = '10-04-20' AND a.role = '2'
> Order BY e.id
> ```
>
> ```
> id | username | date       | accountID
> -: | :------- | :--------- | :--------
>  2 | koala3   | 2010-04-20 | 5        
>  5 | pete101  | 2010-04-20 | 1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=d2e96035e93f6addcea10269365e8bf1)*

Comment: Thank you for your time and help, but what to echo in PHP?

Comment: you can keep your php code, the mysql select does the rest